# jQuery UI: Datepicker month format

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I'm trying to change the format of the month that displays in the popup (not in the date that the picker actually returns. I can't find any option anywhere to do this, is there a hack like using substring() or something?

I'm trying to change what's normally displayed as:

```
<div class="ui-datepicker-title">
    <span class="ui-datepicker-month">January</span>
    ...
</div>
```

To this:

```
<div class="ui-datepicker-title">
    <span class="ui-datepicker-month">Jan</span>
    ...
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try changing the [monthNames](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#option-monthNames) options when invoking datePicker.